# Is there any K-means analog for regression, not culstering?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

Good day
Is there any regression Machine learning model, based on k-means? 
Example (Zillow's Zestimate):
I have a lot of houses(with features like sq.feet and location) and prices. I want to estimate price for a new house by averaging k neighbors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $k$-nearest neighbors regression.  It's not based on $k$-means, but it is based on estimating the price of a new house by averaging $k$ neighbors (in particular, the $k$ most "similar" houses in the training set, for some measure of similarity that you define).  $k$-nearest neighbors is supported in many machine learning toolkits.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, [k-NN_regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#k-NN_regression) - link on proper paragraph.